# How to return the json response from the fetch API

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have a function like so:

```
check_auth(){
    fetch(Urls.check_auth(), {
      credentials: 'include',
      method: 'GET'
    }).then(response => {
      if(response.ok) return response.json();
    }).then(json => {
      return json.user_logged_in;
    });
  }
```

And then I try to do this:

```
if(this.check_auth()){
    // do stuff
} else {
    // do other stuff
}
```

But, `this.check_auth()` is always `undefined`.

What am I missing here? I thought that within fetch's `then()` was where the **resolved** Promise object was therefore I thought that I'd get `true` when the user was logged in. But this is not the case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Use callback

```
check_auth(callback){
    fetch(Urls.check_auth(), {
      credentials: 'include',
      method: 'GET'
    }).then(response => {
      if(response.ok) return response.json();
    }).then(json => {
      callback(json.user_logged_in);
    });
  }

 check_auth(function(data) {
        //processing the data
        console.log(d);
    });
```

In React it should be easier to handle, You can call a fetch and update the state, since on every update of state using setState the render method is called you can use the state to render

```
check_auth = () =>{
    fetch(Urls.check_auth(), {
      credentials: 'include',
      method: 'GET'
    }).then(response => {
      if(response.ok) return response.json();
    }).then(json => {
         this.setState({Result: json.user_logged_in});
    });
  }
```

Comment: Yep. I've tried. There has got to be something else fundamentally wrong with my approach. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This answer doesn't work because this is React and I can't `render` from within the `check_auth` function. Does that makes sense? Does that give you any further idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I thought it would be that easy too. But if I put this in state, anyone could go and download the React dev tools, go into state and simply change `logged_in` to `true` and they're in, bank account numbers etc. all wide open. I want to check if the user is logged in on every API call.

Comment: I think that the state is the property of a react component that is not publicly exposed to modify and hence this wont be a issue, I have seen blogs on React login which use the state themself

Comment: I can't make it work. I thought maybe in production mode it would hide state, but sure enough I can do anything I want to it. I just don't get it.

Answer (score 3):

it can be solved with the es6 `aync` functions

Note: the example is different from what OP asked but it gives some hints on how it should be done

```js
const loadPosts = async () => {

  const response = await fetch(/* your fetch request */);

  const posts = await response.json();

  return posts;

};
```

Comment: when I console.log(loadPosts()) it returned this `[[PromiseValue]]: Array(14)` How can I loop thru them?

Comment: the async function is returning a fulfilled promise which you have to resolve whenever you are calling it. example ```const posts = await loadPosts();```

Answer (score 2):

Async calls doesn't always resolve to be used anywhere within your app when you use `.then()`. The call is still async and you need to call your `if`-statement when you are calling your `fetch`. So anything that relies on the data you are fetching has to be chained to the `fetch` with `.then()`.

```
  check_auth(){
        fetch(Urls.check_auth(), {
          credentials: 'include',
          method: 'GET'
        }).then(response => {
          if(response.ok) return response.json();
        }).then(json => {
          return json.user_logged_in;
        }).then(user => checkIfAuthSuccess(user)); //You have to chain it
      }
```

Wrapping your `if`-statement in a function or however your code looks like.

```
checkIfAuthSuccess(user){

  if(user){
     // do stuff
  } else {
    // do other stuff
  }
}
```

Nice video about async behavior in JavaScript: [Philip Roberts: What the heck is the event loop anyway? | JSConf EU 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)

Comment: Yep. I've tried. There has got to be something else fundamentally wrong with my approach. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Neither of these answers work because this is React and I can't render from within the check_auth function. Does that makes sense? Does that give you any further idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To return data as JSON from Promise you should call it with **await** modifier from **async function**.

For example:

```
const checkAuth = async () => {
const data = await fetch(Urls.check_auth())
                  .then(response => response.json())
                  .then(json => json.user_logged_in)
return data;
}
```

More info about promises you can find [here](https://web.dev/promises/)