# Creating a loop in javascript Async Function

Tags: javascript, loops, promise

```
createDatabase(){
request({
        url: `http://${nodeName}:port?format=json`,
        auth: {
          'username': 'admin',
          'password': 'admin',
          'sendImmediately': false
        },
        method: 'POST',
        json: true,
        body: payload
      },
        function (error, response, body) {
          if (response.statusCode != "201") {
            resolve(response.statusCode);
            done();
          }
          else {
            reject();
            done();
          }
        })
}
```

This is the code I am using to create a database in my application. I need to create multiple databases example - db1, db2, db3 etc.
In such case I want to implement a loop for this. But as this is async, I am unable to handle the same. 
Please suggest how promises can be handled in this case.

Comment: If it is ok with you to use [fetch-api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), maybe you can have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43454125/4636715)

Comment: Promise.all(["some","variables"].map(createDatabase))

Comment: What would you like to loop over? What would be different in each iteration?

Comment: Do you want to create them in series (create one, wait until it is done, then create the next) or do you want to create them in parallel (start creating them all and be notified when they are all done)?  Also, what variable are you changing in your loop - your code does not show that?

Comment: Yes I want to create them in series..

Comment: I want to loop the complete creation request so that it creates the 'n' amount of databases

Comment: More important, I want to wait untill the creation of databases are been done, and success request should be come back

Comment: That is exactly what my answer does.  I still don't know what you want that my answer does not already show.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I used the request-promise module that replaces `request()` with a function that returns a promise so you can use promises instead of plain callbacks to manage when things are done.

Then, if you are OK with creating all the databases in parallel and just need to know when they are all done, you can do this:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

function createDatabase(payload) {
    return rp({
        url: `http://${nodeName}:port?format=json`,
        auth: {
          'username': 'admin',
          'password': 'admin',
          'sendImmediately': false
        },
        method: 'POST',
        json: true,
        body: payload
  });
}

let promises = [];
// some for loop that creates separate payloads to pass to createDatabase
for (...) {
    // create payload for each database here

    promises.push(createDatabase(...));
}

Promise.all(promises).then(function(results){
    // process array of results here
}).catch(function(err) {
    // handle error here
});
```

This collects a promise from each call to `createDatabase()` into an array and then uses `Promise.all()` to tell us when all those promises have finished and offers the resolved value of all the promises into a `results` array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this will not stop the execution of next functions. It will provide the request results, dont know when..!! I want to verify that the databases are been created as in next function call I am fetching the id's of the databasese created.

Comment: @VipulGoyal - Welcome to asynchronous programming in nodejs.  The code you want to execute after all the databases are open goes inside the `.then()` callback or in a function you call from there.  That's how async programming works in node.js.  There is no way in Javascript to make the interpreter "wait" for everything to be done before proceeding.  Instead, you nest functionality inside the asynchronous callback.  Promises help you do that in a cleaner way especially when you're trying to coordinate multiple asynchronous operations.

Comment: @VipulGoyal - Also, if you want help with more of what you're doing, then please show us more code so we can see what else you're trying to do here.  I've answered what you asked given the code you showed.